# Not able to access SpringContext after integrate Atmosphere framework with spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, atmosphere

As I mentioned in the title that After integrating `Atmosphere framework` with `Spring MVC`, I want to access current LoggedIn User by the help of SecurityContext(Or Authentication), But gives me null when I send the ajax request from the JSP page(client side).

Is there any problem with my code or some other problem. Below are my MyController.java and JSP files

**MyController.Java**

```
 
     @Controller
     public class MyController {

     
      @Autowired
      PartyManagementService partyManagementService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/websockets", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String post(final AtmosphereResource event, @RequestBody  String message)
       throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
     
       User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().
                      getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username = user.getUsername();
       Person person =  partyManagementService.getPersonFromUsername(username);

      logger.info("Received message to broadcast: {}", message);
      final int noClients = event.getBroadcaster().getAtmosphereResources().size();
      event.getBroadcaster().broadcast(message);
      return " message successfully send ";
     }
    }
```

### home.jsp

In my home jsp, I provide ajax request which pushes the message to the server.

Comment: What is null ? `username` or `event` ?

Comment: I got user as 'anonymousUser' which is String type. So it gives me classCastException. If i access that user from SecurityContext from another method where AtmosphereResource related stuff not available then it works correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot make a connection between your comment and your code. What line is the ClassCastException ?

Comment: User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().
                      getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in filter order. You should look at output of spring security classes at debug level to control that current user is correctly identified.

Comment: Is there any problem with AtmosphereResource to use with SecurityContext.  Because If i access User from normal method then it gives me correct User.